# A curious case of... undefined reference to `main'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

On Facebook, there was a simple challenge - write "I am a programmer" in your language.

Of course I could do that with

```
print("I am a programmer")
```

which is boring. And I need a mental health check anyway.

So, I wrote a Python3 script that writes a C++ file, tries to compile it, fetches the output of the C++ program, and displays "I am a programmer".

```
from os import system
from subprocess import getoutput
from subprocess import call

def main(string):

    # removes the old version, if it exists
    system("rm -rf program.cpp")

    # creates the file

    f = open("program.cpp", "a")

    output = "#include <iostream>\n"

    f.write(output)

    output = "using namespace std;\n"

    f.write(output)

    output = "int main()\n{\n"

    f.write(output)

    output = """\tcout << "I am a programmer" << endl;\n"""

    f.write(output)

    output = "return 0;\n"

    f.write(output)

    output = "}\n"

    f.write(output)

    # COMPILE!
    call("g++ program.cpp", shell=True)

    # call the program, get its output...
    out = getoutput("./a.out")

    # print the output
    print(out)

main("I am a programmer")
```

...then I it can't compile:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`program.cpp` contains `int main()`, so this can't be a problem.

And when I do `g++ program.cpp` on the command line - not from the Python script - it compiles. No problem. It's frustrating.

**Edit: Content of the generated .cpp file:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "I am a programmer" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to check for typos, what are the contents of the cop file after you run the script?

Comment: The contents of `program.cpp` are completely empty, when you fork off a subprocess to run the compiler. Helpful hint: close the file that you ***think*** you've just written out, before you attempt to compile it.

Comment: Are you sure that your file is flushed to disk before the compiler is launched?  It may be buffered until python exits.

Comment: I added the .cpp file, see above. And yes, the missing f.close() was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Case closed: In my Python program, `f.close()` was missing. The buffer wasn't written to `program.cpp`.

Thanks for your help!